# How can I highlight an element when its clicked, but then also unhighlight other elements?

Tags: angular

I have a component that contains several children components. Something like this:

```
<div class="mainComponent">
    <child-component-1 *ngFor="let childA of childrenA"></child-component-1>
    <child-component-2 *ngFor="let childb of childrenB"> </child-component-2>
    <child-component-3 *ngFor="let childc of childrenC"></child-component-3>
</div>
```

If a user clicks a child-component-1, I want to apply some special styling to it so it's highlighted. Simple enough, just add  (mousedown)="foo()"  (and check if the user is holding 'ctrl' so I can highlight multiple). What i'm not sure how to do though is unhighlight any other child components that are highlighted.

The only thing I can think of is to have all child-component-x's emit an event when they get highlighted. In my mainComponent I can then iterate through all children components and set each to unhighlight. This would involve iterating through all my components every time though, and there could be a lot.

Is there a better way to handle this, or is my idea the correct way?

Comment: In pure javascript this is too easy to ask, if you know how to change a class in a javascript, you also know how to change that to the unhighlighted class for other objects in the same function, so I'm not sure if you are perhaps asking for a css only solution.

Comment: Could you elaborate? If I add a mousedown handler to any of the child-components, then when it fires that child-component has no knowledge of any of the other components and cannot tell them to unhighlight. I can bubble it up to the parent, but then it has to check every child component, which there could be many of.

Comment: If you give your components an ID, you can refer to that ID when you're in the MouseDown function. First you set all your components to the non-highlighted class, then you set the current component that has the mousedown event in the highlight class. All in 1 MouseDown function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do what you want:

```
<div class="mainComponent">
  <child-component-1 
    *ngFor="let childA of childrenA"
    [class.highlight]="isHighlighted(childA)"
    (click)="toggleHighlight($event, childA)">
  </child-component-1>
  <child-component-2 
    *ngFor="let childb of childrenB"> </child-component-2
    [class.highlight]="isHighlighted(childB)"
    (click)="toggleHighlight($event, childB)">
  </child-component2>
  <child-component-3 
    *ngFor="let childc of childrenC"
    [class.highlight]="isHighlighted(childC)"
    (click)="toggleHighlight($event, childA)">
  </child-component-3>
</div>
```

```
highlightedItems = [];

isHighlighted(item) {
  return this.highlightedItems.indexOf(item) >= 0;
}

toggleHighlight($event, item) {
  let idx = this.highlightedItems.indexOf(item);
  let isControl = e.keyCode != 17;
  if(isControl) {
    if(idx < 0) {
      this.highlightedItems.push(item);  
    } else {
      this.highlightedItems = this.highlightedItems.slice(idx, 1);
    }
  } else {
    this.highlightedItems.length = 0;
    if(idx < 0) {
      this.highlightedItems.push(item);  
    }
  } 
}
```